# How to do deep link with NavigationLink SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

My goal is to navigate to the second view from the first view and on the second view navigate to the third view

For clarity I remove some of the code.

This is the first view

```
struct ProfileView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: SettingsView()) {
                        Image(systemName: "gear")
                            .renderingMode(.original)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

This is the second view

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                NavigationLink(destination: EmailView()) {
                    Text("Email")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Settings")

    }
}
```

[image]

Once I click the link on the second view it will go to the third view. But on the third view the navigationBarTitle doesn't change. It's stacked vertically instead.

```
struct SnapUsernameView: View {
    @State var email = ""
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TextField("Your Email".uppercased(), text: $email)
        }
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("Email")
}
```

How do fix the navigationTitle from settings to Email on the thirdview ? and to make sure that the sequence is correct. Thanks

[image: with]

Comment: It should be only one `NavigationView` in view hierarchy, and `NavigationLink` used in it (or child).